# Device id in C2DM

Tags: android, android-c2dm

As far as I know, C2DM is per app per device thing..but my question is ,what is the use of device id and where do we use device id in C2DM?

Comment: what do you mean by "device id"

Comment: Someting to uniquely identify a device..

Comment: device ID is probably the unique identifier for the device. Something like either IMEI/MEID, hardware serial or ANDROID_ID

Comment: Do we use any of them in C2DM..?

Comment: `deviceRegistrationID` from C2DM samples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Device Id** term is used in iPhone and **Registration ID** is the term which we use in Android.

**Registration ID**

An ID issued by the C2DM servers to the Android application that allows it to receive messages. Once the application has the registration ID, it sends it to the third-party application server, which uses it to identify each device that has registered to receive messages for a given application. In other words, a registration ID is tied to a particular application running on a particular device.

**Note:** For detail description follow the [link](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/).

Answer (score 1):

The device ID is afaik your **Google Account**

See "Sender ID"

> An email account associated with the application's developer. The
>   sender ID is used in the registration process to identify a Android
>   application that is permitted to send messages to the device. This ID
>   is typically role-based rather than being a personal account—- for
>   example, my-app@gmail.com.